# How to implement cache in spring-integration?

Tags: spring-integration

I want to implement the cache so whenever table is updated in database ,my entity should get updated.How can i implement caching feature in spring integration ?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Spring Framework Caching Abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).

You would need some mechanism to invalidate the cache when the external resource changes.